# How can I determine my laptop battery's specification?

Tags: battery, compaq-laptop

Is there any application that can be used to detect the exact battery that is in a laptop.
Here is the screenshot I got. I don't know the battery specification because the label has already been erased. How do I determine it?

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/CPU%20Z/cpu.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/CPU%20Z/cpu.png)

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/CPU%20Z/mainboard.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/CPU%20Z/mainboard.png)

*Editor note: These Dropbox images no longer exist*

Comment: The images are broken and can't find an alternative source for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get anything the battery doesn't tell you. But under Linux, the `battery.reporting.technology` or `battery.technology` properties of the hal UDI for the battery gives you what the bettery tells you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a software called [Power Center](http://download.cnet.com/Power-Center/3000-2094_4-10021809.html?tag=mncol):

> Power Center is a battery management program that estimates the amount of time your battery has left to run, rather than the percentage of power left in the battery. It recalibrates its estimate each time and keeps a record of it so future estimates are more accurate. With the help of the Control Center, you can set the Power Center to inform you whenever the battery is lower than a specific percentage, at a specific percentage, or when the AC power goes on or off. In this version the window mode restoration problem has been solved. Version 2.12 includes a few minor bug fixes.

And here some nice battery test program (not really related, but just in case you'll need it):

[Laptop Battery Tester](http://download.cnet.com/Laptop-Battery-Tester/3000-2094_4-10468524.html):

> This program can scan battery voltage, export them and show graph. Export data to MicrosoftExcel, or Picture export. Program can load old picture for compare results, changes and defect. Installer and uninstaller is included.

Comment: this is great but, what I'm trying to do is to validate whether laptop with the same name, in this case compaq presario B1200. Has the same batteries which are compatible.

Comment: If it wasn't compatible - it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

[BatteryMon](http://www.passmark.com/products/batmon.htm) from PassMark... a battery monitor and it show's everything you may want about the battery.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Notebook Hardware Control](http://www.pbus-167.com/nhc/nhc.htm#anchor_download).

[image]